# Ошибка с ImageButton

Tags: java, android

Как я понял проблема с кнопкой только что конкретно понять не могу.

Код ошибки

```
2021-09-24 16:33:57.566 17450-17450/com.buratinoapps.falling E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.buratinoapps.falling, PID: 17450
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.buratinoapps.falling/com.buratinoapps.falling.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ImageButton.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3797)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3973)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8528)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ImageButton.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.buratinoapps.falling.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3973) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8528) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Код MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton startGame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        startGame.findViewById(R.id.start_game);

        startGame.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        });

    }
}
```

Проблему показывает в строке 23

```
startGame.findViewById(R.id.start_game);
```

XML Code MainActivity

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bg_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/mainbackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/start_game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_games_start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bg_main"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: setFlags нужно вызвать до установки разметки setContentView

Comment: Подскажите я правильно вас понял     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Всеравно выдаёт ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, правильное решение или нет, но проблема исчезла, когда я заменил строку 23 на такой вариант:

```
View startGame = findViewById(R.id.start_game);
```

Comment: можете даже View удалить. вы в самом верху указали что ImageButton startGame;